# problemas con node y sequelize

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, orm, sequelize

hola gente tengo un problema con node estoy diseñando un crud utilizando el patron de diseño modelo, vista y controlador. En el controlador me salta el error, es como si se renderizara dos veces. El controlador es el siguiente:

```
exports.proyectoid=async(req,res,next)=>{
    const rul=req.params.url;
    
    const findone= await proyect.findOne({
        where:{
            url:rul
        }
    })
    
    const tare=await tareas.findAll({
        where:{
            proyectoId:findone.id
        }
    })
    const proyectos=await proyect.findAll()
   
    res.render('proyectoid',{
        url:findone,
        proyecta:proyectos,
        tare
    })
}
```

La ruta a ese controlador es

```
route.get('/proyecto/:url',proyectocontroller.proyectoid)
```

y la vista

```
extends index


block contenido
    .contenido-principal
        h1 Nuevo proyecto 
        form.agregar-proyecto(action=`/tareacreate/${url.url}` method="POST")
            .campo 
                label(for="nombre") Nueva tarea: 
                input(type="text"  name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nuevo tarea") 
            .campo.enviar 
                input(type="submit" value="enviar" class="boton")
        .contenedor-acciones
            a(href=`/proyectoeditar/${url.id}` class="boton") editar
            a#eliminar-proyecto(href=`/proyectoeliminar/${url.id}` class="boton eliminar") eliminar
```

El error es

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `nombre`, `estado`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `proyectoId` FROM `Tareas` AS `Tareas` WHERE `Tareas`.`proyectoId` = 2;
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `nombre`, `url`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `proyectos` AS `proyectos`;
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `nombre`, `url`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `proyectos` AS `proyectos` WHERE `proyectos`.`url` = 'index.js' LIMIT 1;

C:\node app\apps task\controller\proyectoController.js:42
            proyectoId:findone.id
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
    at exports.proyectoid (C:\node app\apps task\controller\proyectoController.js:42:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

es como si se renderiza dos veces, porque la primera ves el parametro url es el valor que quiero capturar, y como si despues se renderiza otra ves y el parametro es index.js(la direccion de la ruta)

Comment: El error señaliza findone. **id** no recupera un id estas seguro que esa query te devuelve resultados?

Comment: si me devuelve por que imprime el resultado en la vista, y despues me sale ese error, es como si hiciera la consulta otra vez, pero el paramatro mandado por url da como resultado INDEX.JS

Comment: Entonces tu problema viene de que se invoca dos veces desde dos puntos diferentes

Comment: si pero nose de donde ..